# iterate nested children and display data using vuejs and javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, tree

I have treeview folder structure with nested children. There are some file objects nested into children. I want to display those files details based on node using vue and javascript. Here is the mocked data:

```
 data:[{
  id: 1,
  name: ‘Project A’,
  type: ‘folder’,
  children: [{
    id: 4,
    name: 'Project A-1’,
    type: ‘folder’,
    files: [
      {
        id: 9,
        pid: 4,
        name: ‘file 3-A’,
        type:’file’,
        description: ‘wifi’,
        country: ‘USA'
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        pid: 4,
        name: ‘file 3-B’,
        type:’file’,
        description: ‘VPN’,
        country: ‘USA'
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Services’,
  type: 'folder',
  children:[],
  files: [
    {
      id: 5,
      name: ‘Services-1-A’,
      type:’file’,
      pid: 2,
      description: ‘VPN’,
      country: ‘AUS'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: ‘Services-1-B’,
      type:’file’,
      pid: 2,
      description: ‘WIFI’,
      country: ‘AUS'
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Servers',
  type: 'folder’,
  children:[],
  files: [
    {
      id: 7,
      name: ‘Servers-1-A’,
      type: ‘file’,
      pid: 3,
      description: ‘VPN’,
      country: ‘CAD'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: ‘Servers-1-B',
      type: ‘file’,
      pid: 3,
      description: ‘WIFI’,
      country: ‘CAD'
    }
  ]
}]
```

**UI CODE**:

```
<el-row style="background: #f2f2f2">
                  <el-col :span="6">
                   <div class="folder-content">
                     <el-tree
                         node-key="id"
                         :data="data"
                         accordion
                         @node-click="nodeclicked"
                         ref="tree"
                         style="background: #f2f2f2"
                         highlight-current
                         >
                         <span class="custom-tree-node" slot-scope="{ node, data }">
                             <span class="icon-folder" v-if="data.type === 'folder'">
                              <i class="el-icon-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                              <span class="icon-folder_text" @click="showFiles(node.id) >{{ data.name }}</span>
                             </span>
                         </span>
                     </el-tree>
                   </div>
                 </el-col>
                 <el-col :span="12"><div class="entry-content">
                  <ul>
                      <li aria-expanded="false" v-for="(file,index) in files" :key="index">
                           <span class="folder__list"><input type="checkbox" :id= "file" :value="file">
                           <i class="el-icon-document" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          <span class="folder__name">{{file.name}}</span></span>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
                   </div></el-col>
                 <el-col :span="6"><div class="preview_content"></div></el-col>
               </el-row>
```

**method:**

```
    showFiles(id) {
  let f = this.data.filter(dataObject => {
    if (dataObject.children && dataObject.children.id === id) {
      return false
    } else if (!dataObject.children && dataObject.id === id) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  })[1]
  this.files = f.files
  console.log(this.files)
}
```

I want to get those file details if traverse through deep children. If i click children folder 'Project A-1' then i want to display those files inside that children. I have tried to filter out but it is displaying only root folder files if any. I am not able to display nested files inside children.

I am getting whole node details with prototype instead of files

How to iterate those and display?

Comment: Please provide all of the relevant code.

Comment: Hi Hev ... I have updated the necessary code

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. I have written comments in the code to explain my thought process.

```js
showFiles(id) {
  for (const dataObject of this.data) {
     if (this.dataObject.children && this.dataObject.children.id === id) { // check if file has children and if the child id is the same as the id. If it is, the files are the files of the nested child
       this.files = this.dataObject.children.files;
       break;
     }
     if (!this.dataObject.children && this.dataObject.id === id) { // if the data object does not have children and the id is the same as the id being looked for, the file is the root folder 
       this.files = this.dataObject.files;
       break;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried with filter but i am not getting any error but  getting prototype properties. i have updated my question

Comment: Do you want the `filter` method to be used? It may not be the most efficient solution in this case. Have you tried the above solution? Did it work for you? With the above solution, you don't need to filter.

Comment: Yes it is working but all the node details is showing on click